# OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0' M1-Cheap

Tags: python, django

> > > import weasyprint
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/**init**.py", line 325, in 
> > > from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/css/**init**.py", line 27, in 
> > > from . import computed_values, counters, media_queries
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 16, in 
> > > from ..text.ffi import ffi, pango, units_to_double
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/text/ffi.py", line 404, in 
> > > gobject = _dlopen(
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/text/ffi.py", line 391, in _dlopen
> > > return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 150, in dlopen
> > > lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library
> > > backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
> > > File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/django/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 827, in _load_backend_lib
> > > raise OSError(msg)
> > > OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': dlopen(gobject-2.0-0, 2): image not found.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'

Comment: try to install a different version  pip install PyGObject